# PhoneGap ChildBrowser Executing JavaScript

Tags: iphone, browser, cordova

I wonder if this is possible to execute JavaScript inside phonegap childbrowser window so we can manipulate websites under phonegap app?

Looking at the big picture as one can create a function in Objective-C which executes that JS into childbrowser (modifying childbrowser.m and childbrowser.h files) and creating JS wrapper of it so one can call JS function to execute JS inside childbrowser.

I want you to modify ChildBrowser for me to have that functionality so I shouldn't lost doing it. At least give me initial steps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright I just tried and it worked in a single go. That was amazing! I just modified ChildBrowser plugin of PhoneGap and it worked.

**UPDATED**

I finally got few minutes to update the answer for those who will encounter the same issue.

ChildBrowserCommand.h

```
- (void) jsExec:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
```

ChildBrowserCommand.m

```
- (void) jsExec:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options; {
    [childBrowser executeJS:(NSString *)[arguments objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

ChildBrowserViewController.h

```
- (void)executeJS:(NSString *)js;
```

ChildBrowserViewController.m

```
- (void) executeJS:(NSString *)js {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

ChildBrowser.js

```
/* MIT licensed */
// (c) 2010 Jesse MacFadyen, Nitobi

function ChildBrowser()
{

}

// Callback when the location of the page changes
// called from native
ChildBrowser._onLocationChange = function(newLoc)
{
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange(newLoc);
}

// Callback when the user chooses the 'Done' button
// called from native
ChildBrowser._onClose = function()
{
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose();
}

// Callback when the user chooses the 'open in Safari' button
// called from native
ChildBrowser._onOpenExternal = function()
{
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onOpenExternal();
}

// Pages loaded into the ChildBrowser can execute callback scripts, so be careful to 
// check location, and make sure it is a location you trust.
// Warning ... don't exec arbitrary code, it's risky and could cause your app to fail.
// called from native
ChildBrowser._onJSCallback = function(js, loc)
{
    // Not Implemented
    window.plugins.childBrowser.onJSCallback(js, loc);
}

/* The interface that you will use to access functionality */

// Show a webpage, will result in a callback to onLocationChange
ChildBrowser.prototype.showWebPage = function(loc)
{
    PhoneGap.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage",loc);
}

// close the browser, will NOT result in close callback
ChildBrowser.prototype.close = function()
{
    PhoneGap.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.close");
}

// Not Implemented
ChildBrowser.prototype.jsExec = function(jsString)
{
    // Not Implemented!!
    PhoneGap.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.jsExec", jsString);
}

// Note: this plugin does NOT install itself, call this method some time after deviceready to install it
// it will be returned, and also available globally from window.plugins.childBrowser
ChildBrowser.install = function()
{
    if(!window.plugins)
    {
        window.plugins = {};    
    }

    window.plugins.childBrowser = new ChildBrowser();
    return window.plugins.childBrowser;
}
```

My global variable.

```
var CB = null;
```

On my DeviceReady event.

```
CB = ChildBrowser.install();
if (CB != null) {
    CB.onLocationChange = onCBLocationChanged;
}
```

I can execute any JS into webpage using.

```
CB.jsExec("alert('I am from ChildBrowser!');");
```

I hope my contribution to this will bring smile on your face.

Comment: Could you share some of what you did to modify the ChildBrowser plugin?

Comment: Yes sure I can share it but how?

Comment: Actually I am willing to share because it feels really good when you can help others but the problem is I can't handle Git and I am noob about it. Is there a guide for it?

Comment: I have used Git before but using old school method like "try and fail". I wanted to learn Git the professional way as I'm succeeding so far. I understand how it works now at least. I will soon update my many of the stuff to public which are just lying in my hard drive.