# Phonegap Childbrowser opening a Phonegap page.

Tags: android, ios, cordova

When using phonegap to make an iOS app, can the ChildBrowser plugin open a remote page which can use phonegap functions?

For example:
index.html in the phonegap app, calls childbrowser.showwebpage("http://www.website.com");
Can that www.website.com use phonegap functionality?

Or is it only possible with pages in the phonegap/www directory?

Answer (score 1):

Since childbrowser is actually a native UIWebView (on iOS, idk about Android), you have all the benefits of the nitro javascript engine (as of June '11). That means the page/website you are loading can run it's own javascript code. However, the PhoneGap middleware is bootstrapped in the app itself and since UIWebView is native, I don't see how you could use any PhoneGap functionality unless you wrote a plugin to do just that.  I may be completely wrong here though...

EDIT: See this thread here: [PhoneGap ChildBrowser Executing JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757066/phonegap-childbrowser-executing-javascript)

He has modified childbrowser to accomplish this very task

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
try {    
  var url="www.webpage.com";

    //both of these should work...
    //window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url);

  var CBrowser = new ChildBrowser();
  CBrowser.showWebPage(url);    

}catch (err) {  
    console.log("Error:"+err);  
}
```